# Innosetup Unexpected End of File error

Tags: installation, inno-setup

The code is here http://pastebin.com/gmZRsyQR

When I try compiling it - right above [Files] it says the error "Line 98: Column 1: Unexpected end of file." I'm at such a loss - how do I fix this?

Comment: You are missing `end;` after line 95 (of that pastebin). If you were using proper formatting, you would find this by yourself.

Comment: You were right - thanks, and you're right I need to clean up the code, but I'm just trying to scramble this together.

Comment: You're welcome! Now looking on it once again, there's actually an extra `begin` on line 79, not a missing `end;`.

Comment: I apologize, but upon adding more to it, I broke it again, I'm very new with Inno setup (obviously) and I don't know what I broke this time. http://pastebin.com/b4hFqXUq Now it highlights function NextButtonClick and says Line 85, column 1, Identifier Expected. What do I need?

Comment: Your `case` statements makes no sense (in each you are asking for the same `CurUninstallStep` value). And once again, you have improper code formatting and extra `begin` on lines 57, 66 and 75 as far as I can see. First try to learn how to properly format your script code. Then you'll be able find these problems by yourself.